# Synchronously retrieve image resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I require a function that takes `URL` as an `argument` to some `image`, and synchronously `returns the resolution`. I would like the function to simply hang while the image is being retrieved.

Something along those lines:

```js
function getImageDimensions(imageData) {
    $("body").append("<img id='hiddenImage' src='" + imageData />"');

    /* Wait until image is loaded */

    var width = $('#hiddenImage').width();
    var height = $('#hiddenImage').height();
    $('#hiddenImage').remove();
    return width;
}
```

Comment: `Wait until image is loaded` - therefore it won't be synchronous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** I completely miss this. You can do it with simply moving your code inside `$img.on('load', function() {...}` like below.

```js
function getImageDimensions(imageData) {
  var $img = $(`<img id='hiddenImage' src='${imageData}' />`);
  
  $img.on('load', function() {
    /* Wait until image is loaded */
    var width = $('#hiddenImage').width();
    var height = $('#hiddenImage').height();
    $('#hiddenImage').remove();
    alert('width = ' + width);
    console.log(width);
  });
  
  $("body").append($img);
}

getImageDimensions(`https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6RvS.png?s=48&g=1`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Alternatively**
Rather than trying to make it synchronous why don't you try making it `async`. Update your function to be `async` return [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and `resolve` it when `img` is `loaded`.

Call `getImageDimensions` from another `async` function and use `await getImageDimensions` just in below I have done it with `test`.

```js
async function getImageDimensions(imageData) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    var $img = $(`<img id='hiddenImage' src='${imageData}' />`);
    $img.on('load', function() {
    /* Wait until image is loaded */      
      var width = $('#hiddenImage').width();
      var height = $('#hiddenImage').height();
      $('#hiddenImage').remove();
      alert('width = ' + width);
      resolve(width);
    });

    $("body").append($img);
  });
}

async function test() {
  let a = await getImageDimensions(`https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6RvS.png?s=48&g=1`);
  console.log(a);
}

test();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Or alternatively you can use `Promise` with `then` and `resolve` it from `onload` after which `callback` function will be called from `then`. So it will work similarly as `synchronous` code. You can write code which should be done after `img` is loaded inside `then`.

```js
function getImageDimensions(imageData) {
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    var $img = $(`<img id='hiddenImage' src='${imageData}' />`);
    $img.on('load', function() {
      resolve($img);
    });
    $("body").append($img);

  }).then((result) => {
    /* Wait until image is loaded */
    var width = $('#hiddenImage').width();
    var height = $('#hiddenImage').height();
    $('#hiddenImage').remove();
    alert('width = ' + width);
    console.log(width);
  });
}

getImageDimensions(`https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6RvS.png?s=48&g=1`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
function getImageDimensions(imageData) {    
  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function(data){
    var width = data.target.width;
    return width;
  }
  image.src = imageData;
}
```

Comment: This is not synchronous.

Answer (score -1):

A function cannot return multiple values. However, you can get the similar results by returning an array containing multiple values. You can return an array of values.

```
function getImageDimensions(imageData) {
    $("body").append("<img id='hiddenImage' src='" + imageData />"');

    /* Wait until image is loaded */

    var width = $('#hiddenImage').width();
    var height = $('#hiddenImage').height();
    $('#hiddenImage').remove();
    var size = [width, height];
    return size;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also return an object if you want to label each of the returned values for easier access and maintenance

```
function getImageDimensions(imageData) {
    $("body").append("<img id='hiddenImage' src='" + imageData />"');

    /* Wait until image is loaded */

    var width = $('#hiddenImage').width();
    var height = $('#hiddenImage').height();
    $('#hiddenImage').remove();
    var size = {
        width: width,
        height: height        
    };
    return size;
}
```

Comment: This is not the issue, returning multiple values in an array is easy. My issue is how to replace the comment with actual code, or otherwise make the execution synchronous.